# Как в runtime вызвать редактор ImageList

Tags: delphi, vcl

Как в `runtime` вызвать редактор `ImageList` ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак. Он в рантайме недоступен. Схожий вопрос - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179738

Comment: Если долго долго покопатся, найти интерфейс и точку входа в процедуру клика по ImageList где привязан "десигнер", и запустить её, а она в свою очередь находится в одной из dll самого Delphi которую прийдётся подшить к проэкту - то может быть сие заработает. Но думаю оно того не стоит. Вот если вы пишите кастомный ImageList (допустим что б картинки хранились в ресурсах) тогда да, наследуетесь, и диалог будет виден в дизайнере.